# shared library function not getting called in lollipop

Tags: android, gcc, arm, android-5.0-lollipop, eabi

I have got the .so library from a third party company which used android ndk to build that and I am supposed to call some functions defined in this library.

I am able to compile the code and linking also happens properly. However the function call doesn't really happen i.e. I don't get any error in calling the function but in reality it is not calling the function. I can say that because it is not changing the size which is passed as input and which is the output from the exported function.

How can I debug this? Is it something to do with compiler name mangling ?

I am using android lollipop. Same mechanism was working in kitkat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was: we were using old ndk. We should use latest ndk provided by google.